# How to change the order of star rating at woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store and I want to change the order that star ratings are displayed in the single product page. Now the star rating system is from 1 to 5. I want to display first the 5 and go to 4 - 3 - 2 - 1. Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: This is only about CSS I think…

Comment: I dont think css can change the order. Lets see :-)

Comment: There is no order it's just about dynamic width and alignment… But CSS is not my speciality.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the original question.

Comment: @GeorgeCh Could you provide a screenshot of what you want to do & a screenshot of current state.

Comment: @Sajjad Hossain Sagor this is now the star rating https://ibb.co/hWneJd  . I want tto be the 5 star first and then 4.3.2.1

Comment: It seems your rating order are coming from either a custom plugin or theme.

Comment: @SajjadHossainSagor here is the code of template https://pastebin.com/rNYnqJxs

Answer (score 0):

Based on your pastebin , i have edited it so that the ordering becomes 5-4-3-2-1 , check it out if it works properly

```
`https://pastebin.com/A2gXJnDu`
```

Comment: thanks for your time. I made the same changes and still the same outpout as default. This didnt changed the order from 5 to 1.